# Back button event listener not works while returned back from second page to first html page cordova phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I am having two html pages, i use multiple panels inside it, the back button event listener works fine inside 1st html page, if i move from first to second html page , here back button event listener not works. vice versa.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML & JavaScript for the second page?

Comment: Sorry for the delay sir, I have added Github link here, Please check with that. https://github.com/Niyascofi/PhonegapCode/blob/master/Second_html_page.txt